# "Fanatic" Badge days reset due to maintenance

Tags: support, badges

As I was trying to achieve "Fanatic" Badge, and I was at about 22 days streak, and logged in two days ago, when the site was down for maintenance, and I could not browse the site, so I thought I got the "site browsed/visited" for that day.
The next day (yesterday) I logged in and my Fanatic Badge was back to 1 days..

Is this supposed to happen?

Did this happen to other people?

Can I get my visited days streak back?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371236/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-oct-30-31-2021-starting-at-1300-utc/371434#comment1239078_371236)?

Comment: So they dont actually care..

Comment: It was planned maintenance and it wasn't down for long. At the end of the day, they are just badges that don't really have any meaning. Just redo it. I could understand if it was a more difficult badge, but it's not too taxing to restart if you are that intent on getting the badge